# Symfony2 Form - File Type validation (mimeTypes) for HTM / HTML

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have a form where I am uploading a file. 
I would like to validate if the file is in HTM/HTML format.

Is there an existing mimeType for HTM files in symfony?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a validation constraint for the MIME-type of the upload in your `FormType`:

```
'file' => new File( array(
    'maxSize' => '20M',
    'mimeTypes' => array("text/html")
));
```

You can read more about it here: [File: mimeTypes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html#mimetypes)

Comment: i though about that aswell but the mime-type does not guarantee it to be (valid) html. Maybe a combination of mine-type and my code inside a custom validator would be the safest way.

Comment: If you also want to check whether the file is valid, you could use something like "[DOMDocument::validate](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.validate.php)".

Comment: jeah checking for validity if file-content contains xml tags would be the next step

Comment: And this could be done using a custom validator, like you suggested.

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php would be an alternative to validate generic xml files :)

Comment: @nifr, I do not need to check if the HTML is valid, only that the uploaded file is a HTML file.